# How do I interactively read the input text for this Emacs function?

Tags: regex, emacs, buffer

I am new to Emacs functions. Today is my first attempt to create a function.

I know that count-matches will tell me how many times a regex appears in the rest of the buffer, but most of the time I need to count from the beginning of the buffer. So I tried this:

```
(defun count-matches-for-whole-buffer (text-to-count)
  "Opens the ~/.emacs.d/init.el file"
  (interactive "sText-to-count:") 
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (count-matches text-to-count))
```

I put this in ~/.emacs.d/init.el and then do "eval-buffer" on that buffer.

So now I have access to this function. And if I run it, it will ask me for text to search for.

But the function only gets as far as this line:

```
beginning-of-buffer
```

I never get the count.  Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

1. You should use `(goto-char (point-min))` instead of `beginning-of-buffer`.
2. `count-matches` will not display messages when called from lisp code unless you provide a parameter indicating so.

Try this code:

```
(defun count-matches-for-whole-buffer (text-to-count)
  (interactive "sText-to-count:")
  (count-matches text-to-count (point-min) (point-max) t))
```

Comment: The buffer could be narrowed. If  you want the number of matches in the visible part of the buffer, and not in the whole buffer, then `point-min` and `point-max` are the right things to use. Otherwise, use `1`, not `point-min`, and `(1+ (buffer-size))`, not `point-max`.